# Modifying NSMutableDictionary by key path

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist, kvc

I have a `NSDictionary` with nested `NSDictionary/NSArray` (Generated through a JSON).

I need to remove objects in multiple places according to some logic imposed on me.

For instance lets say that the dictionary has some structure like:

```
{
   "Array1" : [
      {
          "InnerArray1" : [ 
               {
                   "some conditional field" : Evaluate this ...
               }
           ],
          "More Properties : ....
      }
   ],
   "Array2" : {
       ... some complex inner structure
                  {
                      // some inner object to remove according to "evaluate condition"
                  }
   }

}
```

When I iterate the "`Array1.InnerArray1...`" and evaluate some condition to `true` , I need to remove objects in a disjoint location.

Ideally I could do something like

```
foreach item in Array1.InnerArray1 {
   if item evaluates to true {
      // evaluate the disjoint location...
         remove Array2.....InnerObject(s) where ConditionField == true
   }
}
```

Currently it is very awkward to iterate the inner objects and mutate them on the same pass (and very hard to read).

Given I have created a deep mutable copy of this whole data tree, is it possible to remove nested objects using `kvc` or another mechanism without nested iterations?